# relationship between writing systems, scripts, and font. Terminology clarification required

Tags: terminology, arabic, writing-systems, transcription

I want a clarification on terminology. A language is written in a particular script . but there are various styles for writing a script. For e.g. arabic is written in arabic script, and it can be written in Kufic style or Naskh or Dewani or Nastaleeq etc. 
Are these writing styles called fonts or these are writing styles and fonts are different interpretations of these writing styles?
 Kindly clarify the standard terminology.

Comment: The terminology is inconsistent because it's technological terminology and the technology has changed radically. Think "dialing a phone" in the absence of a dial, "reading a paper" on a screen, etc. All writing used to be done by hand, and then it changed. And changed again, differently, in different histories with different languages. There is no standard -- just do the best you can.

Answer (score 3):

These variants have different and inconsistent names in English across the languages.

**Style**

The word "style" seems to be preferred for the variants of the Arabic script; people refer to styles of the Arabic script very [often](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-explain-the-difference-between-Nastaliq-style-and-Shikaste-style-of-Persian-and-Arabic-calligraphy).

**Script**

This is also often used for Arabic script variants, even though it is ambiguous with the script system (e.g. Arabic, Roman, Cyrillic, Chinese). It is also the standard way to refer to different historical forms of Chinese characters (e.g. oracle bone *script*, clerical *script*, cursive *script*) and for calligraphic variants of the Roman alphabet (e.g. Uncial *script*, Gothic *script*).

**Hand**

Slightly literary word, one that is more frequently used in the artistic calligraphic world than the linguistic world.

The words *typeface* and *font* are not appropriate for this level; they refer to more things in printing and computing, below the level that you are looking for.

Comment: Might be worth adding that to refer to "scripts" in the sense of Arabic, Roman, Cyrillic, Chinese, without ambiguity with "script" as in style, one sometimes calls them by the *type* of script they are: the Arabic abjad, the Roman and Cyrillic alphabets, the Chinese logograms. I'd guess this is reasonably common in linguistics publications.

Comment: I guess *style* in the context of writing refered to the technique necessary with a certain kind of implement+medium and dissociated from there on. Ever tried writing with the wobbly stylus of a cheap, broken ballpoint pen? It has no style at all! But also compare *to set*, Ger *Satz* (polysemous, I mean "set of [i.e. characters]), *Schriftsatz* (as young as printing?), *Zeichensetzung* "punctuation"; Compare *key, chifre, code*? Today *style* means decorative type. *Lettering* is a word meaning ..?

Comment: *Hand* neatly compares to *tongue*